# How to check if list a is bigger than list b and then replace it

Tags: python, list, for-loop

So I was thinking to create a compare list where I have a list A (Old_list) that contains:

```
{'name': 'Jesus and Mary', 'sizeslist': ['Low', 'Medium', 'High']}
```

and a list B (product) that contains

```
{'name': 'Apple and Juice', 'sizeslist': None}
```

So what I did at the beginning was that I checked if the length of sizeslist was higher than the list B, then it should replace it.

```
old_list = [{'name': 'Jesus and Mary', 'sizeslist': ['Low', 'Medium', 'High']}]

while True:
    product = [{'name': 'Apple and Juice', 'sizeslist': None}]

    if product not in old_list:

        a = product['sizeslist']

        if old_list != []:
            old_list_value = old_list[0]['sizeslist']

            if len(old_list_value) < len(a):
                print("Higher than old_list!")
                old_list[0] = product
                break

            elif len(old_list_value) > len(a):
                old_list[0] = product
                break
        else:
            old_list.append(product)
```

the problem is that I am getting `object of type 'NoneType' has no len()` and my question is how can I improve the code so that I don't get the error of no len() and also be able to just change the sizeslist instead of the whole list.

EDIT:

```
old_list = {'name': 'Jesus and Mary', 'sizes': ['Low', 'Medium', 'High']}

while True:
    new_list = {'name': 'Apple and Juice', 'sizes': None}

    try:
        if new_list['sizes'] not in old_list['sizes']:

                if old_list['sizes'] < new_list['sizes']:
                    print("New element!!!")
                    old_list['sizes'] = new_list['sizes']
                    break

                elif old_list['sizes'] > new_list['sizes']:
                    old_list['sizes'] = new_list['sizes']
                    break

        else:
            randomtime = random.randint(5, 10)
            time.sleep(randomtime)
            continue

    except Exception as err:
        logger.error(err)
        randomtime = random.randint(1, 2)
        time.sleep(randomtime)
        continue
```

Comment: What you call "lists" really are *dictionaries*.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], i.e. code anyone can execute to reproduce the problem. BTW: You will probably find the mistake while extracting that MCVE, which is also why questions without it are considered off-topic.

Comment: I will complete this thread with a code:) Give me few minutes!

Comment: you question does not match with your problem statement. are you trying to validate your logic, or want to find your why you are getting `object of type 'NoneType' has no len()` error? both are separate things.

Comment: Excuse me @GaurangShah but you might be right. i think what I want is that I want to improve and also would like to know what the reason why I am getting the error aswell.

Comment: You are getting the error because `a = None` form `a = product[0]['sizeslist']`. Maybe you can change `'sizeslist': []` in `product` instead of `None`. But what's your expected output?

Comment: Hello @iGian - If you check the answer by Filip. I have commented what my output should be!

Comment: I guess it would be easier for users to help if you edit your question with all the useful details.

Comment: Alright, I think I will need to re-edit it totally I guess haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you want to compare `'sizeslist'` and not whole dictionary. If so you should take into account case where your `'sizeslist'` might not be `list` but `None`. Here's way to handle that.

```
a = {'name': 'Jesus and Mary', 'sizeslist': ['Low', 'Medium', 'High']}
b = {'name': 'Apple and Juice', 'sizeslist': None}

listA = a['sizeslist']
listB = b['sizeslist']

if not listB or (listA != None and len(listA) > len(listB)):
    b['sizeslist'] = a['sizeslist']
else:
    print("Nope")

print(b) # -> {'name': 'Apple and Juice', 'sizeslist': ['Low', 'Medium', 'High']}
```

Comment: I have added a new code! I assume you might be actually the solution. Would you mind take a look and see if we are stil in the same page :) ?

Comment: I see typo `['sizes']` instead of `['sizeslist']` and unnecessary `try` `except` conditions. Try cleaning your code first.

Comment: There we go! Excuse me! :)

Comment: `product` shouldn't be dict inside array, just dict if you want to access it like so `product['sizeslist']`. Also you'll get error if you check `len(a)` since a might be `None`, before checking its length you should check if it isn't equal to `None`.

Comment: Oh that might be the issue why I am getting it in that case? Do you have any suggestion in that case what I should improve in a code example by the code I am using?

Comment: Exactly what I said in previous answer, set `a` to dict instead of dict inside array and add `if a != None ...:` in your conditions.

Comment: Oh yeah! So basically I just changed now with adding to a dict and I changed `if old_list != []:` to `if old_list[sizeslist'] != None:` I assume it is something like that what you meant and then continue whatever you want to do?

Comment: Yes, that will get rid of error. Also if you want to update value of product's `'sizeslist'` you should change `old_list.append(product)` to something like `product['sizeslist'] = old_list['sizeslist']`, but I'm not sure what you're exactly trying to achieve. If you could provide example output to your question that would be very useful.

Comment: Oh okey! Well basically I didnt thought about the dict at all. So what I did now is that I changed to dicts and my idea was that I just want to compare the `sizeslist` with each other where I first have a old_list and new_list. Whenever the new_list has more element (I think thats the correct word) then it should replace the more element as the new *old_list*. And if that happens then it should just print out ("Added new Old_list with higher element. but before that I need to make a compare where I check if the `sizeslist` in `new_list is not `old_list['sizeslist']` before I continue the next.

Comment: So in that case a output would be it checks whenever (in my case) product is not inside the old_list (In that case I would just compare the `sizeslist`. If its not inside the list then we check if the length (Doesn't need to be len but if the elements is more inside the product than in old_list` if it is - then we print out there is new higher element and update the value. BUT if its not higher than we just update the value and doesn't print out.

Comment: Your questions are very unclear, you already provided inputs in your question (2 dictionaries) now please just add exactly what value you are expecting to be assigned to what variable to help me understand you better.

Comment: Alright so what I want to do is that I first want to check `if product['sizes'] not in old_list['sizes']:` If its true then we check `if product['sizeslist'] has more elements than old_list['sizeslist']` then we update the value and print ("New element added"). `if product['sizeslist'] has NOT more elements than old_list['sizeslist']` and we just update the value and do not print anything. That's it.

Comment: `if product['sizes'] is not None:` then `for value in [i for i in product['sizes'] if i not in old_list['sizes']]:` `old_list['sizes'].append(j)` and if you want to print it `print(j)`

Comment: Strange, I tried to do `old_list = {'name': 'Jesus and Mary', 'sizeslist': ['Low', 'Medium', 'High']}` \n `product = {'name': 'Apple and Juice', 'sizeslist': ['Low', 'Medium', 'High']}` \n `if product['sizeslist'] not in old_list['sizeslist']:` and it prints everything inside the if statement, it shouldnt right? Since it has the same sizeslist

Comment: `if product['sizeslist'] not in old_list['sizeslist']:` you do that this way because sizelist is a list and because of that you will check if list isn't element of another list, instead you should check every element like i shown in my answer.

Comment: Correct! i have tried to do like yours now! I have edited my thread which my current version I have now. I changed my None value as a 'none' (String) instead. The only concert I have now is that what if I have 1 element in a old_list that is etc 'None' and new_list has a element that is 'Hello', I dont think it would ping because of the `old_list['sizes']` is as same long as `new_list['sizes']` ?

Comment: If you'll compare each element of old_list with elements in new_list and there won't be `None` element in new_list you'll successfully append it using my method.

Comment: Oh okey so basically I just need to add `if new_list['sizes'] not in old_list['sizes']:` before you if statement to check if it contains in old list or not and then I would be able to run the same code as your answer in that case

Comment: That won't work, instead try `if new_list['sizes'] != None and any(i not in old_list['sizes'] for i in new_list['sizes']):`

Comment: Alright I will give it a shot! Just a question, what if a value changes from etc `Sizes : [Hello, world]` to `Sizes: None`, Wouldnt that mean that it wouldnt mean that it wont update the previous value to None?

Comment: Wops, Sorry for the double "wouldnt mean"! - Is it possible to make it so it also updates the value to None? If yes then how would the solution for that look like?

Comment: Sorry but I already gave you enough working code and I believe you can figure simple things like this one yourself. Feel free to accept my answer if you feel it was useful to you.

Comment: Dziekuje! Appreciate it alot!

Answer (score 0):

```
if old_list != []:
            old_list_value1 = old_list['sizeslist']
            old_list_value = list(oldlist_value1[0])

            if len(old_list_value) < len(a):
                print("Higher than old_list!")
                old_list[0] = product
                break

            elif len(old_list_value) > len(a):
                old_list[0] = product
                break
```

This might work. Also notice that you are comparing strings length, where old_list[0] has length of 3 characters and None is nothing. Try to change None to some value.